# Is it able to hold Paypal Adaptive Payment (Chain Payment)?

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

i am new to paypal, now i encounter one problem which is, i know how does the adaptive payment chain payment work already, but what i am trying to do is, i want to hold the payment, until the merchant release it, the sender only will be charged.

This is my scenario :

sender want to assign the job to multiple receiver, but before the job started, i (merchant) want to pre-charge the sender first, because if the receiver completed the job, the sender account itself do not have any credit balance, the merchant will be fedup, in this case, before i want to start the job, i want to pre-charge the sender first, and hold the payment. Once the receiver completed the job, i(merchant)  will release the payment to all the receiver. If the receiver is unable to complete the job, i will return the money to the sender.

Is it got anyway to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Delayed Chained Payments:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id091QF0I30YK__idad5b73a3-e25a-415e-8a91-84f5f3141d52

How to Make a Delayed Chained Payment Using Adaptive Payments:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Below is the reference of Refund API:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/

But there is a little different from your needs.
The buyer should first pay primary reciever, primary reciever will hold the funds until they call ExcutePayment.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is what i want!